# If I click accept or reject the request the data should be added into my db but from request list it should be removed like facebook friends list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to C#. I have a page where I am getting a request for reject or accept.But here I want to do accept and reject like when I click accept or reject it should be stored but it should be removed from the request list. I am new to this thats why I dont have any code for that. I hope it wouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps 1 - Create two tables , one for accepted/rejected request and one for request in queue.

Steps 2 - When anyone sending request then insert request into request-in-queue table.

Steps 3 - When accepting/sending request then insert into accepted/rejected table and delete from request-in-queue table.

Below code is for insert and delete operations. table and fields name are just for demo . change code according to your need:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=xxxx;user id=sa;password=xxxxx;integrated security=yes"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into request-in-queue values("+id+",'"+requestorname+"')", con);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("data inserted");
            }

            SqlCommand cmddel = new SqlCommand("delete from request-in-queue where id=" + id, con);
            int j = cmddel.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (j > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("data deleted");
            }
        }
```

Please refer below article for more database operations with c#.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/crud-operation-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: thank you so much bro Ill try it ill be back to you If I get an error